# changing the SVN repository link

Tags: eclipse, svn, adt

I'm involving in an **Android** project and it's uses **SVN** for source controlling. the **reference link(URL)** for the **SVN repository** has been changed due to an unavoidable reason. can I change the repository URL within eclipse. or should I reconnect to the server and take the revissions. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use svn relocate eclipse with svn plugin should have such option on repository. You can also use command line (if you have)

[COMMAND LINE](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.relocate.html)
[ECLIPSE REFERENCE](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/SVNaction/switch.php)